# rename multiple files possible unintended interpolation

Tags: perl, rename

I'm using brew rename to rename multiple files...

```
file-24.png => file.png
file-48.png => file@2x.png
file-72.png => file@3x.png
```

the first one is succeed with,,

```
rename 's/-24//g' *
```

the second and third...

```
rename 's/-48/@2x/g' *
```

and getting `Possible unintended interpolation of @2 in string at (eval 2) line 1.`..

escaping doesnt work..

```
rename 's/-48/\@2x/g' *
```

other possible ways to rename multiple files like this case are also welcome..

Comment: *"escaping doesnt work"* Okay but what *does* happen? And is this the Perl `rename`, because `rename 's/-24//g' *` won't do anything useful in Perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what "*brew rename*" is, but if it uses normal regex

```
's/pattern/q(@replacement)/e'
```

This uses [/e modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) to evaluate the replacement side as code, where [q() operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) (single quotes) is used to insert literal characters.

Another way is to use [`\x40`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) for `@` character

```
's/pattern/\x40replacement/'
```

or just escape it, use `\@` in the replacement.

This is suitable for when there's just one character to deal with, like here. if there's more than that then it's easier to single-quote the whole thing, with `q()` (for which we need `/e` flag).

---

Can't help it but ask -- are you certain that you want to have `@` in a file name?  That character gets interpreted in various ways by many tools. For instance, sticking that file name in a variable in a Perl script leads to no end of trouble.  Why not even simply `file_at_2x.png`?

This may be more of a curiousity, but if you have a lot of files you can rename them all with

```
's{ \-([0-9]+) }{ ($r = $1/24) > 1 && qq(_at_${r}x) || q() }ex'
```

This captures the number `([0-9]+)` into `$1`. Then, it finds the ratio (`$r = $1/24`) and if that is `>1` then (`&&` short-circuits) it replaces `-number` with `_at_${r}x`, otherwise (`||`) removes it by putting an empty string, `q()`.

I use `{}{}` delimiters so that I may use `/` inside, and `}x` allows spaces inside, for readability.

Please test this carefully with (a copy of) your actual files, as always.

Comment: thank Youu.. i mean rename from homebrew... this is what is working others not `rename 's/-48/\x402x/g' *`.... ios uses `@` for image pixel...

Comment: @karina  You are welcome :)  That would mean that `rename` doesn't take full regex.  Thanks for feedback -- I didn't know about the `@`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old and maybe the version of `rename` that apt-get installs is lightly different or improved. However, escaping with a single backslash seems to work:

```
$ rename -n -v 's/-48/\@2x/g' *
rename(foo-48.txt, foo@2x.txt)
```